# C# Pager issue with dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have create a ajax pages custom control with previous and next link and now when I am adding a drop down to the controls it is not working as desired..

I have used the code form http://www.flixon.com/Articles/Custom-ASPNET-Data-Pager-Control-22.aspx

When I am adding a drop down then on selected index change the previous and next button are getting disappeared. I believe this is due to I am binding the drop down in pre render event

Comment: -1: Not enough information given about the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding drop down for paging in pre render event you can also bind it at the time of binding grid.

```
if (gridView.BottomPagerRow != null)
{
  GridViewRow myGridViewRow = gridView.BottomPagerRow;
                DropDownList ddCurrentPage = (DropDownList)myGridViewRow.Cells[0].FindControl("ddCurrentPage");

//To do to bind Drop down
}
```

and you can also explicitly call drop down selected index change event

Here is the code for pager template

```
<PagerTemplate>                                           
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="imgPagePrevious" CssClass="Pagingbutton" Text="<"CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" OnCommand="imgPagePrevious_Command" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCurrentPage" runat="server" CssClass="PagingDrop" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCurrentPage_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="imgPageNext" CssClass="Pagingbutton" Text=">" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" OnCommand="imgPageNext_Command"/>                                          
  </PagerTemplate>
```

Try this.